# Why the code for android does not work in IOS?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

So I have a code that is working on android and on IOS does not. This code distincts the list inside the select tag of HTML using javascript.

How can that be possible that the code for Android is not working on IOS.

Can someone help me with this?

```
         var list = $scope.test_.filter((x,i,a) => a.findIndex(y => y.member_type === x.member_type) == i);            
         $scope.list_ = list;
```

Regards.

IT says that SYNTAX ERROR: Unexpected Token '>'

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: try to use regular functions instead of arrow in your "filter" and "findIndex"

Comment: how to do that sir?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your browser doesn't support arrow functions. try to use regular functions instead:

```
  var list = $scope.test_.filter(function (x, i, a) {
      return a.findIndex(function (y) {
               return y.member_type === x.member_type;
      }) == i;
  });
  $scope.list_ = list;
```

Comment: Sir? Can I have another question?

Comment: Your code does work sir, but this code is to select the distinct value inside the array. and put it to `<select>` tag of html. the return value has a duplicate now, but before it does not have. how can we do that with this code sir?

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake. updated the answer, try it out now